# connection is insufficiently secured Error in Azure cosmos DB Data Migration tool

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to load JSON file data into cosmos DB container using Azure cosmos DB data migration tool but I'm unable verify my database connection when clicked on verify. The error is as follows

[image]

I took the 'Primary Connection String' from my Cosmos DB account and appended the database name

`AccountEndpoint=https://n0-dev-cdb-01.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=**********;Database=Accounts;`

Note: in the Advanced Settings of the Target Information tab I changed connection Mode from DirectTCP to Gateway but still facing the same error.

Your help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can you check [TLS](https://i.imgur.com/wpHiePn.png) version and once select TLS 1.2 and retry to connect it?

Comment: @Bhavani, as I checked TLS version 1.2 is already selected, I retried with TLS 1.1 also but no luck, is anything else to check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the **Networking** tab in Azure Cosmos Database, and navigate to **Connectivity**. Select the **TLS 1.0** protocol and save it, as shown below:

[image]

After updating the protocol, go to the Azure Cosmos DB Migration Tool and use the connection string in the following format:

```
AccountEndpoint=<url>;AccountKey=<key>;Database=<db>;
```

Verify the connection. It will connect successfully, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bhavani, I tried in another environment with Different DB account connection string and it worked.